# Using r.js to build entire project without needing overhead of require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I have a project with multiple javascript files, all formatted as AMD modules. I'm using r.js as part of my build process (using [this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) grunt plugin to handle everything).

After I build my project, I end up with a concatenated, minified file that has jQuery, followed by all my modules ordered correctly. That said, these modules still make calls to `require` and `define`, so I need to include the entire require.js library when I send over my minified JS file to the client.

Is there any way I can build my JS such that I don't need to send `require.js` to the client? Like, when I build all my JS, can I just strip out the calls to `define` or `require`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This [article](http://www.webdeveasy.com/optimize-requirejs-projects/) from 2013 says there's no solution yet, but I'm hoping theres a fix now.

**EDIT**: One good suggestion I've heard is to use `Almond.js`, which I can do if that's the best solution to date. I was just hoping I didn't have to ship over any 3rd party library in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't using almond with r.js do that?

Comment: ^ will be your best option next to re-writing as CommonJS and using browserify (I kid).

Comment: PS - last I checked the require.js minified file was 16KB - where is the overhead you're referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use almond as a replacement for require.js in your built module.  Have it loaded first to give you what you need.